# Develop hololens in unity with macbook

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm new with unity and hololens and I started to explore it.
I have a macbook (I don't know if it is a problem).

I downloaded Unity with all the components (Vuforia, IL2CPP etc.).

When I change project settings for the hololens development I have some problems. 
In particular when I check the box "Virtual Reality Supported" I don't find in the list below the Hololens option. 
Also if I click on "+" button. I see: Vuforia, Oculus, OpenVr but not Hololens!

Furthermore also in the field: "scripting backend" i found only "none" and "IL2CPP".
Now, as I already say, i have downloaded all the components during the installation process. 
Which is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Hololens runs on UWP, you need Windows.  This is because the windows development libraries do not run on mac (or any Unix).

Your only option is to use something like [boot camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468) to install windows 10 on your Mac (fast and works very well), or [run a VM](https://kb.parallels.com/en/4729) (a lot slower, but can be convenient if you develop on the mac and only build in the VM).

Everything should work fine with the exception of the hololens emulator, which does not work on every MacBook hardware.

Answer (score -1):

You have to download the correct tools for Hololens development, here is the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install-the-tools

Comment: The windows 10 SDK is not available on Mac, meaning this guide cannot be followed  ):