# Anyone already tried developing for Hololens 2 with current Macbook Pros?

Tags: augmented-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality, bootcamp

Currently i am planning to buy a new Macbook Pro for IPad and Hololens 2 development. Has anyone already tried if developing for Hololens 2 works with current Macbooks with Bootcamp running Windows 10? I am especially concerned that the Holographic Remote functionality is to much to handle for the Radeon Pro 5500M.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely possible to develop HoloLens app on MacBook. You can use something like Bootcamp to install windows 10 on your Mac and install the required tools for development. See [Install the tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install-the-tools?tabs=unity).

Especially if you need to test app in HoloLens emulator, please double check the system requirements [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-hololens-emulator#hololens-emulator-system-requirements).

The similar question see [Develop hololens in unity with macbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595762/develop-hololens-in-unity-with-macbook)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found that thread but the thing is i didnt plan to use the emulator. I wanted to use holographic remoting with which i just stream my app from Unity to the Hololens 2. I couldnt find out if this would be possible. The minimum system requirement for the streaming would be a Radeon R9 290 or a GeForce 970 GTX. So i am not so sure if the Radeon Pro 5500M in the Macbook Pro would be sufficient for the task.

Comment: Based on some public benchmark data, Radeon R9 290X has much better reflection handling and faster complex splatting, some indicators are close. I would suggest you having a try on your MacBook, as Andrey mentioned, please use Bootcamp to install Win10 first.

Answer (score 0):

Remoting is based on coupling of PC and Hololens components and isn't available on any other OS except the latest Windows 10.

Comment: Yes thats why i wanted to use Bootcamp with Windows 10 on the Macbook.